# Is it too late to add an Admin panel, Login and Register function?

Tags: php, laravel, crud

Just stared experimenting with Laravel 5.4 and have created a really simple CRUD (Create, Read, Update and Delete). Works like a charm, 5.4 has really made many things a lot more easy. Since i'm am more or less learning Laravel and not that confident in my skills yet, i want to ask should i start a new project and create the option for the user to register and login, so he can view his own dashboard and then implement the CRUD or should just continue from my current CRUD project and try to add the login, register and admin panel ? Will post source code if needed.

Comment: You can just continue with the current project. Laravel makes it very easy to add middleware through the routes files, so you can change things like authentication gates and route paths whenever you like.

Answer (score 0):

laravel 5.4 allows you to automatically create registration and login from the command line using php artisan make:auth. Follow this:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication
Then from there you can now build your CRUD.

Comment: Yeah, done that plenty of times. Sadly, after i entered "php artisan make:auth" the CRUD is gone and all i can see is the Login and Register buttons. I hope its fixable as i am working on it now. Thanks for the help though and if you have some advice for fixing this, please share.

Comment: Of course. It's still there. It be sad if "php artisan make:auth" deleted it all. My guess is i have to reconfigure all the routes and models along with the views.

Comment: What you can do is add the routes to the authenticated user view on this folder here: resources/views/auth

Comment: You can now add the CRUD routes on this file created: home.blade.php - the dashboard for logged-in users

Comment: What do you mean by adding the routes ? Extend them or ? Appreciate it if could be more specific.

Comment: tell me if am getting you right am a bit confused,you want to be able to do the CRUD functionality once you log in,right?

Comment: Exactly what i want.

Comment: you remember the get routes to display the CRUD pages you have created??Add them to app.blade file that is in layouts folder on the else part.

Comment: on the home.blade.php file is where you can add the CRUD files